# Selenium wait until some element is appear

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
<img style="width: 640; height: 640;" id="img108686545" alt="Loading Word War..." src="www.something.com/anu.jpg">
```

How to wait until this element appears on the page. The value of `"id"` attributes is dynamic and always changing on every reload

I've tried:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30) # seconds
```

But I can't figure out the exact time to wait

Ultimately, I want to get the `src` attribute of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use CSS_SELECTOR as follows:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10) # max waiting time
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"img[alt='Loading Word War...']")))
```